# Earth Engine API (Python) Retrieves script found at a given path as a module not working

Tags: google-earth-engine, python-2.7

[Earth Engine API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#require) says that require(path) returns an object that represents exported members from the required module.

When I try to import [ee-palettes](https://github.com/gee-community/ee-palettes) with:

```
palettes = require("users/gena/packages:palettes")
palette = palettes.misc.tol_rainbow[9]
print("palette",palette)
```

I get this error:

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2d55998c0e3e> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 palettes = require("users/gena/packages:palettes")
      3 palette = palettes.misc.tol_rainbow[9]
      4 print("palette",palette)

NameError: name 'require' is not defined
```

Maybe is it only working with JavaScript because in the Playground Editor it works ?